# How to fill Datagridview with Textboxes

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am quite new to programming and I am usually learning from courses on YouTube or directly tutorials from Youtube.
My problem is I want to load file from CSV file and then update the loaded file into DataGridView. But to do so I was following a tutorial but I dunno what table to use.

```
private void btnOtvor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
                {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource = Readcsv(ofd.FileName);                                     
                    labelErrMsg.Text = "Subor otvoreny spravne";
                    labelErrMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

But when I am creating the ADD button:

```
private void btnPridat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridViewZamestnanci.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);
            dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource = dataGridViewZamestnanci;
```

it doesnt see the DatagridviewZamestnanci, there should be datatable but since I loaded it from CSV file directly I am confused and honestly lost...

Can somebody help me, please ?

Comment: One thing you should be aware of… _”You cannot programmatically add rows directly into the grid when the grid is data bound”_ … so the code… `dataGridViewZamestnanci.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);` … will not work.

Comment: Is what you want to do is add the “new” row to the grids data source not the grid itself. If `Readcsv(ofd.FileName)` returns a `DataTable`, then, is what you could do is cast the grids data source to a `DataTable` like… `DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource;` … then add the new row to “that” `DataTable`, `dt`. Something like… `dt.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, You will get an error stating that... *"you cannot programmatically add rows to a grid that is data bound."* ... If you attempt to execute the line of code…

```
dataGridViewZamestnanci.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);
```

you will get this error.

However, since you claim the grids data source is a `DataTable`, then, you could “cast” the grids `DataSource` to a `DataTable`, then add the new row to “that” `DataTable` instead of directly adding the row to the grid. This change may look something like…

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource;
dt.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);
```

If the code is going to add/update/delete rows in the grid, then, it may be easier to make the grids `DataSource` a “global” variable. Then, you can avoid “casting” the grids `DataSource` to a `DataTable` each time you want to add a row. To do this, you would define a global `DataTable` variable called something like `GridDT`…

```
DataTable GridDT;
```

Then, in the current code, change…

```
dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource = Readcsv(ofd.FileName);
```

To…

```
GridDT = Readcsv(ofd.FileName);
dataGridViewZamestnanci.DataSource = GridDT;
```

then the second code snippet above could be simplified to…

```
GridTDT.Rows.Add(textBoxMeno.Text, textBoxTel.Text, textBoxProfesia.Text, textBoxTpp.Text);
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try your suggestions, I hope I will be able to understand. :) So excited to try it on this weekend.

Comment: Gosh, sir. It worked like a charm !!! Thank you SO much. :) Cheers and I wish you nice weekend ! :)